# What is DDI (D&D Insider)?

Tags: dnd-4e, tools, dnd-insider

I have seen this referenced in several questions. I've actually seen people use links into the DDI website in their answers that I can't get to since I don't have a subscription. I know its an online resource for D&D material.

What exactly is it? Is it more than an online rulebook?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

DDI consists of several different parts, each of which are imho quite worth the money. If you have a subscription to DDI you get:

- Access to the Dungeon and Dragon magazines. While the individual quality may vary I've found both magazines a very good resource for ideas, both as a player and a DM.
- Access to the [Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx), a web interface to all published races, classes, items, monsters, and rules. You get the full text, including any errata, without having to haul your books around.
- Access to [several other tools](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Tool.aspx?x=dnd/4new/tool/adventuretools). These include the Monster Builder, a program for the DM to customize his monsters, as well as some Flash utilities useful to create ability scores and build encounters.
- Updates for the [Character Builder](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Tool.aspx?x=dnd/4new/tool/characterbuilder). This is probably the single most valuable point of all advantages. The CB makes building legal characters a breeze since the program takes care of checking feat prerequisites and other calculations for you.
- And last but not least a nifty icon next to your name in the official forums. ;)

I personally find DDI to be a valuable resource although it is definitively not required. It makes many things easier (building characters, customizing monsters, checking a feat or item without having to browse through a dozen books to find it, ...) without invading too much into the game.

One "disadvantage" should be noted, however: new material always appears one month after the book's release date in DDI - after all, WotC needs a motivation for people to still buy their books. ^^

Comment: I'd vote this up with one change: not all DMs are guys. ;)

Comment: WoTC has announced that going forward, book releases and Compendium updates will be in sync: http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/27252609/315_DD_Insider_Update

Answer (score 1):

The "Learn More" links on the [subscribe page](http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Subscription.aspx) are informative.

Note that some of the features, such as the Character Builder, are Windows-only, so Mac and Linux users are out of luck.

Comment: And they are not cleanly enough coded to run in Wine. (See http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=666 for details)

Comment: That link appears to be for a 3e character builder, and the more specific problem than "unclean code" for the 4e character builder, is that it was built using dotnet 3.5 which does not run in wine.

Comment: Technically-minded Linux users might want to look at [Mono](http://go-mono.com/status/) for running the .Net 3.5 DDI apps—if they're not working now, then possibly in the future.

Comment: This is no longer the case.  The Character Builder is now written in Silverlight, which also works on Mac OS X and at least some Linux systems.  The other Adventure Tools are due to be released as web applications soon, as well.

Comment: @rjbs does the CB work on some Linux systems, or just Moonlight? Last I heard, things didn't yet work on Linux.

Comment: Currently running Ubuntu. Installed moonlight in firefox and it registers as silverlight being installed (doesn't ask me to install it, like it did before I installed moonlight), but the CB does not load. About to try downloading it again and give it another shot.

Comment: The new Silverlight-based Character Builder needs at least Silverlight (SL) 4. Since the latest stable moonlight is only feature-complete for SL 2 and the latest beta for moonlight is for SL 3, it will be a bit while before linux users can use the new builder..

Comment: @Gaius that is what I figured. I am slightly disappointed by this.