# Where can I download the Dragon and Dungeon Magazines PDFs?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, tools, dnd-insider

Several answers to [What kind of take-away/offline material does D&D Insider (DDI) give you?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3180/what-kind-of-take-away-offline-material-does-dd-insider-ddi-give-you) mention PDFs of *Dungeon* and *Dragon*.

Where can I find the link to download these PDFs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, only D&D Insider subscribers can download issues.  However, assuming you are already a member, each issue is compiled into a single PDF after all of the articles for that issue are released, so you typically can't download a PDF of the current issue until the end of the month. Once all of the articles are released, a "Download Complete Issue" link and button will appear in the upper right hand corner of the issue's homepage (this applies to back issues as well, which can be accessed from the "[Issue Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150830111617/http://archive.wizards.com:80/DnD/Issues.aspx)" link).